# A line which randomizing a number between two values

Tags: c

my problem this time is not using a line but understanding it,
i received this line from my teacher to randomize a number between the MIN and MAX values, and it works perfectly, but i have tried to understand How exactly and i just couldn't.
I would be happy if anyone could explain it to me step by step (please not i'm not 100% sure how the rand() function works)

Thanks!

```
int number = (rand() % (DICE_MAX - DICE_MIN +1)) + DICE_MIN; // Randomizing a value between 'DICE_MAX' and 'DICE_MIN' which can be defined on the head of this program.
```

Comment: just try is on a piece of paper with `1` and `6` as min / max... try it for a few values for rand()...

Comment: I suggest you split the line up in smaller and simpler parts, doing only a single operation. Then step through the code (or do it on paper with some specific values) to see what's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [`rand()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) generates a random (well, pseudo-random to be precise) number. The `int` returned from it has a large range, so you need to scale it to necessary range.

Assuming `DICE_MIN` to be `1` and `DICE_MAX` to be `6`, you need to generate random integers in the range [1, 6]. There are 6 numbers in the range, and `DICE_MAX - DICE_MIN + 1 = 6`. So whatever integer you get from `rand()` the value of `rand() % (DICE_MAX - DICE_MIN + 1)` will be in the range [0, 5]. Adding the minimum of the required range `DICE_MIN` to it shifts the range to [1, 6].

This is a very widely practiced technique for generating random numbers in a given range.

Comment: Technically, the range of `rand` in many implementations is not that big (in VC++ it's [0, 32767]), and this method produces severely skewed distributions when the target range is not extremely narrow.

Answer (score -1):

### rand:

**Function**: Random number generator.
**Include**:  `stdlib.h`
**syntax**: `int rand(void);`
**Return Value**: The function `rand` returns the generated pseudo  random number.
**Description**: The `rand` function generates an integer between `0` and `RAND_MAX` (a symbolic constant defined in `stdlib.h`). standard C states that the value of `RAND_MAX` must be **at least `32767`**. If `rand` truly produces integers at random, every number between `0` and `RAND_MAX` has an equal probability of being chosen each time `rand` is called.

### How it works?

Take an example of rolling a dice (six sided). The remainder operator `%` is used here in conjugation with `rand` as :

```
rand % 6;
```

to produce integers in the range `0` to `5`. This is called scaling. The number `6` is called scaling factor. But, we need to generate number from `1` to `6`. Now we shift the range of numbers produced by adding `1` to our result (`1 + rand%6`).

In general

```
n = a + rand() % b;
```

where `a` is the **shifting value** (which is equal to the first number in the desired range of consecutive integers, i.e, to lower bound) and `b` is equal to the width of the desired range of consecutive integers.
In the provided snippet of your's

```
int number = (rand() % (DICE_MAX - DICE_MIN +1)) + DICE_MIN;
```

`DICE_MAX - DICE_MIN +1` is desired width and `DICE_MIN` is the shifting value.
Further reading: [Using `rand()`](http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx).

Comment: @downvoter; Leaving a comment should be appreciated.

Comment: 1. That description provides implementations details which are not guaranteed by the standard (the minimum range required is 0-32767, and IIRC there are no requirements on the period). 2. Don't call that number "scaling factor", you are not scaling anything, you are doing a modulo operation. Actual scaling would preserve the uniform distribution, modulo produces a skewed one.

Comment: I am agree with your first reason but disagree with the second one.

Comment: Note that “Actual scaling” is impossible. It is impossible to uniformly map 32768 values to 6. Any fair algorithm needs to throw some values away and/or to draw several values at least some of the times.

Comment: @haccks: if you are not scaling (since you aren't applying a *linear* transformation that maps the input range over the output range), why would you call it scaling factor?

Comment: @haccks “Factor” is the name of the operand of a multiplication. What you call a “scaling factor” is not a factor http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/factor#Noun (but it would be if you were doing scaling, that is, multiplying by a scale http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_(ratio)).

Comment: @PascalCuoq; (*Note that “Actual scaling” is impossible. It is impossible to uniformly map 32768 values to 6....*) , I do not get your point.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: if  work in FP you can (obviously with precision limited by  machine). `double out=rand()*6.0/RAND_MAX;`. Of course your output will have granularity of 6/RAND_MAX, which can definitely introduce distortions.

Comment: My point is that if you intend to fix the real problem that your algorithm does not produce a uniform distribution, even switching to a multiplication will not help. You need a more sophisticated algorithm than just a multiplication or just a modulo anyway. This sort of algorithm is already described in StackOverflow, but it is not necessary to mark this question as duplicate of that question since this one does not insist on uniformity.

Comment: @MatteoItalia; OK. I understand why you are confused with `factor` thanks to @Pascal Cuoq for the link. Edited now.

Comment: @PascalCuoq; I read about this *scaling factor* in [C How to Program](http://www.amazon.com/How-Program-7th-Deital/dp/013299044X).